# PostgreSQL: Does PostgreSQL support Persian Calendar?

Tags: postgresql, calendar, persian

Oracle support Persian Calendar but need to know does PostgreSQL support Persian Calendar?

If yes, then how can we set default calendar type as Persian instead of Gregorian in PostgreSQL(In Oracle we can use NLS_CALENDAR to set default Calendar).

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, PostgreSQL only supports the Gregorian calendar and has some support for the Julian date system.